# Exception while loading data from Mysql in spark

Tags: mysql, exception, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am getting the below exception while running spark code to fetch the data from MYsql. can soneone please help.

code is below

```
    private static final String MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company";
    private static final String MYSQL_USERNAME = "test";
    private static final String MYSQL_PWD = "test123";

    private static final SparkSession sparkSession =
            SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark2JdbcDs")
                       .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///tmp/tmp_warehouse") 
                       .getOrCreate();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //JDBC connection properties
        final Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
        connectionProperties.put("user", MYSQL_USERNAME);
        connectionProperties.put("password", MYSQL_PWD);

        Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM emp");

        List<Row> employeeFullNameRows = jdbcDF.collectAsList();

        for (Row employeeFullNameRow : employeeFullNameRows) {
            LOGGER.info(employeeFullNameRow);
        }
```

16/09/23 13:17:55 INFO internal.SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:///tmp/tmp_warehouse'.
16/09/23 13:17:55 INFO execution.SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT * FROM emp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the DistributedFileSystem FileSystem implementation
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getScheme(FileSystem.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2634)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.makeQualifiedPath(SessionCatalog.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createDatabase(SessionCatalog.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.(SessionCatalog.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.catalog$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.catalog(SessionState.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState$$anon$1.(SessionState.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at sparksql.sparksql1.main(sparksql1.java:40)

below is pom file

```
    <!-- Hadoop Mapreduce Client Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hadoop Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spark  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spark SQL  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: miss a slash: "file:///tmp/tmp_warehouse"

Comment: tried that as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have added both hadoop-core and hadoop-common in pom.xml.
Remove hadoop core and try it